# How can I run sql query on excel table

Tags: sql, excel, jet

I want to run sql query on an excel table:

```
select * from Range[A1:Z50]
```

I managed to do that. Sadly I discovered that the solution I found was based on Jet:

```
ConnectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
```

My client has windows 7 with office professional plus 64bit and the jet does not exist
I think I need to install MDAC - but I cant install anything.

Do you know of other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Ace Provider rather than Jet, the rest of the code will be the same

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
```

Comment: Thanks I found this one on the web - but this one is a dll as well, no? I think that access installation is required.

Comment: No, it's installed with excel I believe inin versions 07 and later

Answer (score 0):

Install [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 'SELECT you_columns FROM [Sheet1$]')
```